# How to monitor execution of long running stored procedure in Oracle DB_

Tags: c#, oracle, odp.net

I have a stored procedure that is preparing data for staging area for further use. This procedure has several steps that each last several minutes. It is invoked from C# front end. Here is simplified procedure flow:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1
AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO T1 SELECT ... FROM T2;
  INSERT INTO P1 SELECT ... FROM P2;
  INSERT INTO Q1 SELECT ... FROM Q2;
END;
```

It is very simple to invoke this in c# code (OracleConnection, OracleCommannd, ExecuteNonQuery...).
However, since this procedure will be executed from front-end by user, it would be very informative if he/she can monitor progress of this procedure. What I have found so far is OracleConnection.InfoMessage event and RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR function. 
I am adding

```sql
BEGIN 
  RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20001, 'My message text');
EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN NULL;
END;
```

in my stored procedure with hope that InfoMessage event will be raised which is not. Here is InfoMessage event handler which is set during OracleConnection initialization (Connection.InfoMessage += OnInfoMessage):

```
private void OnInfoMessage(object sender, OracleInfoMessageEventArgs e)
{
  foreach (OracleError err in e.Errors)
  {
    ShowSomeText(err.Message);
  }
}
```

After removing BEGIN EXCEPTION block error is caught in C# code but InfoMessage has not been fired in this case too. 
What I am doing wrong in this case? 
I have used similar technique for MsSql server and it works smoothly. Do I miss some session/connection related setting?

PS

I am trying to avoid usage of another connection that might query some system objects or user log tables. This would be used as fallback scenario.

Comment: I would say you catch the exception you throw thus it is handled and has no effect any more. Try it without the exception when others ...

Comment: take a look at v$longops - you can write your own progress messages http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/REFRN/GUID-F2802C36-066C-493E-8255-C08CC79B87FB.htm#REFRN30227

Comment: @Sir Rufo: The idea is to catch exception here since there are additional commands later. I am trying to make something similar to Ms Sql Server's RAISERROR (SomeText 10, 1) WITH NOWAIT which allows continuation of the script. I.e. it is not considered as error an is triggered in InfoMessage.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: Without actual testing this looks like it might serve the purpose but there are some prerequisites that I am not sure that can be met (about optimizer and gathering statistics). This might affect already established processes and that is not an option currently.

Comment: No, you just write progress messages, the progress is then avail as you execute in that v$ data dictionary view

Comment: @thatjeffsmith: It means that I need to poll this view every N seconds. Correct? I could easily add log tables where I can monitor progress (insert row after every operation) and querying it from different thread and connection.That approach (either with v$longops or log tables) might be fallback scenario. But I prefer event based notifications. As I might mention already :) if Ms Sql have it I expect that Oracle have it too.

Comment: Your question is about monitoring long running processes but you are using RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR and that is designed to stop the current process.  You might consider DBMS_APPLICATION_INFO.SET_MODULE although you would need to have a separate connection to pull back that content ... but looks like you already have another connect to look at error message !?

Comment: yes it's polling based. your program marks progress points, which are then available upon request

Comment: @Stilgar: Yes. It may looks contradictory but I have used same approach with SqlConnection class and InfoMessage event handler. However, for Ms Sql it is documented behavior and is useful when you need to monitor long procedures without additional connection. I am trying to solve this for Oracle in similar manner.

Comment: SET_MODULE would probably work for that.  You would pull from V$SESSION.  Would likely need additional connection though.

Comment: After searching for OracleConnection.InfoMessage working examples (without success) and reading about OracleDependency and change notification it seems that some kind of polling is way to go for this request.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it simply by creating a sequence and generating sequence value saving it in your C# application and then creating procedure which make use of autonomous transaction and calling it each time you are entering the step.

```
    drop sequence sq;
    create sequence s1; 

    drop table status;
    create table status(id number, descriptions varchar2(100));
```

-- This procedure will update status in the status table

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE update_status (id_in IN Number,description_in IN varchar2,dml_type_in IN varchar2) AS
      PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION;
      id_1 number:= id_in;
      description_1 varchar2(100):=description_in;
      dml_type_1 char(1):=dml_type_in;
    BEGIN
    if dml_type_1='I' then
     insert into status values(id_1, description_1);
    elsif dml_type_1 = 'U' then
     update status set descriptions=description_1 where id=id_1;
    else 
     delete from status where id=id_1;
    end if;
    commit;
    END;
```

--This is your main procedure

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE SP1 (id_in IN number)
    AS
    BEGIN
    --step 1
    update_status(id_in,'Entering Step 1','I');
     dbms_lock.sleep(30);
    --step 2
    update_status(id_in,'Entering Step 2','U');
     dbms_lock.sleep(30);
    --step 3
    update_status(id_in,'Entering Step 3','U');
     dbms_lock.sleep(30);
    update_status(id_in,NULL,'D');
    END;

    --Run procedure from 1st session
    exec sp1(<whatever the sequence value is>);

    --Check status from second
    select * from status where id = <whatever the sequence value was>
```

If you are coding in website you can use something like ajax/jquery stuff been a while since I coded in C#

> Warning: I have been wrong more than I have been right so follow basic
>   principal of software engineering and always test the code before
>   using it in production.

Comment: This is what I call "log table" approach and will be used if I do not resolve usage of OracleConnection.InfoMessage event. This question is exactly about Oracle DB and InfoMessage event. I have used SqlConnection and InfoMessage event to capture RAISEERROR from long running procedures and it works as expected. However, I cannot achieve the same with Oracle and RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR.